# Select closest Div at Window height using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this:

```
<div class="blocks">
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="block1"></div>
            <div class="block2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="block1"></div>
            <div class="block2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
            <div class="block1"></div>
            <div class="block2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <script>
        $(function(){
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            var columnHeight = $('.col1').height(); //col class can vary
            var adHeight = (0.65 * windowHeight);
            if(columnHeight > adHeight){
                //get the closest div showing at adHeight height and append iframe src after this div
                $ex = closestDiv('col1'); //function will be called to get closest div
                $ex.after(
                    'adblock'
                );
            }
        });

        function closestDiv(column){
            //block of code ??
            return 'div'; //should either be block1 or block2 class
        }
    </script>
```

I am trying to get the closest div for a col class that is close to the adHeight.

This way, i can append a new html ad after that div.

Is this possible via jquery?

Comment: The dom is blissfully ignorant to such silly things as dimension, and position. While it would be possible to calculate the height of all the bits above your element, there is no magic method to do it =(

Comment: Can you restate - 'I am trying to get the closest div for a col class that is close to the adHeight.'  What do you mean by closest?

Comment: It seems he just wants to compare which col it's Y-coordinate is closest to the adHeight's bottom Y-coordinate. But I might be wrong :)

Comment: I suggest querying the height of the ad, querying all column heights and subtracting them from window.height sort the heights of the cols and then compare to ad.  Insert ad into one closest.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I am looking for the div closest to the adHeight pertaining to a particular 'col' class. For example, i am trying to decide to either have the ad show after block 1 or block2 child div of the 'col' class.